# Trouble with numpy arrays and matrices while doing backpropagation and gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aCibgK1PTWWu9by6XFdCfh) video tutorial series by Dan Shiffman about creating a small "toy" neural network library.

The tutorial uses JS and a matrix library he teaches how to code, earlier in the series. I, however, use numpy.

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qB2nwJxNVxM) video he programs gradient descent and backpropagation. However, because I'm using numpy, my code doesn't seem too work. If anyone can help I'd be super thankful!

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def dsigmoid(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, Inum, Hnum, Onum):
        self.Inum = Inum
        self.Hnum = Hnum
        self.Onum = Onum

        self.lr = 0.1

        self.weightsIH = np.random.rand(self.Hnum, self.Inum) * 2 - 1
        self.weightsHO = np.random.rand(self.Onum, self.Hnum) * 2 - 1

        self.biasH = np.random.rand(self.Hnum) * 2 - 1
        self.biasO = np.random.rand(self.Onum) * 2 - 1

    def feedForward(self, inputs):
        hidden = np.dot(self.weightsIH, np.array(inputs))
        hidden = hidden + self.biasH
        hidden = sigmoid(hidden)

        outputs = np.dot(self.weightsHO, hidden)
        outputs = outputs + self.biasO
        outputs = sigmoid(outputs)

        return outputs

    def train(self, inputs, targets):
        # Feed Forward
        hidden = np.dot(self.weightsIH, np.array(inputs))
        hidden = hidden + self.biasH
        hidden = sigmoid(hidden)

        outputs = np.dot(self.weightsHO, hidden)
        outputs = outputs + self.biasO
        outputs = sigmoid(outputs)

        # Calculate errors
        errorsO = np.array(targets) - outputs

        # Calculate gradients with derivitive of sigmoid
        # TODO: Use numpy for gradient calculation (if possible)
        gradients = dsigmoid(outputs)
        gradients = gradients * errorsO
        gradients = gradients * self.lr

        # Calculate deltas
        hiddenT = hidden[np.newaxis]
        weightsHODeltas = np.dot(gradients, hiddenT)

        # Adjust weights by deltas
        self.weightsHO = self.weightsHO + weightsHODeltas

        # Adjust bias by gradients
        self.biasO = self.biasO + gradients


        errorsH = np.transpose(self.weightsHO) * errorsO


        # Calculate gradients with derivitive of sigmoid
        # TODO: Use numpy for gradient calculation (if possible)
        gradientsH = dsigmoid(hidden)
        gradientsH = gradientsH * errorsH
        gradientsH = gradientsH * self.lr

        # Calculate deltas
        inputsT = np.array(inputs)[np.newaxis]
        weightsIHDeltas = np.dot(gradientsH, inputsT)

        # Adjust weights by deltas
        self.weightsIH = self.weightsIH + weightsIHDeltas

        # Adjust bias by gradients
        self.biasO = self.biasO + gradientsH
```

Here is the code I'm running:

```
from NN import NeuralNetwork
from random import shuffle

def main():
    nn = NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1)

    dataset = [
        {
            "inputs": [0, 0],
            "outputs": 0
        },
        {
            "inputs": [0, 1],
            "outputs": 1
        },
        {
            "inputs": [1, 0],
            "outputs": 1
        },
        {
            "inputs": [1, 1],
            "outputs": 0
        }
    ]


    for x in range(100):
        for data in dataset:
            print(data)
            nn.train(data["inputs"], data["outputs"])
        shuffle(dataset)

    for data in dataset:
        print(data)
        nn.feedForward(data["inputs"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Notes\Programming\Machine Learning\NN From Scratch\Yet Another Neural Network Library\main.py", line 38, in <module>
main()
File "c:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Notes\Programming\Machine Learning\NN From Scratch\Yet Another Neural Network Library\main.py", line 30, in main
nn.train(data["inputs"], data["outputs"])
File "c:\Users\ghost\Desktop\Notes\Programming\Machine Learning\NN From Scratch\Yet Another Neural Network Library\NN.py", line 77, in train
weightsIHDeltas = np.dot(gradientsH, inputsT)
ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Comment: "However, because I'm using numpy, my code doesn't seem too work." Where ? How ? Why ?

Comment: You using python 3. Right?

Comment: Indent the line after `def sigmoid(x):`

Comment: @Bazingaa it's indented in my code, fixed it in the question

Comment: @JérémyBlain there are issues with dot multiplication because of the sizes of the matrices, and weird stuff with multiplication of arrays and matrices.

Comment: @DeepakSaini yep

Comment: @Ghost Then you should edit your post with your issues, the error displayed and so on. It will help us to help you !

Comment: @JérémyBlain Done!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I know, but I'm using it on values which have already been passed through sigmoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to some help from Zoma_alchemist and the [toy neural network github](https://github.com/CodingTrain/Toy-Neural-Network-JS/blob/master/lib/nn.js) I've managed to fix my code to work pretty well!

Here is the NN class:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def dsigmoid(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, Inum, Hnum, Onum):
        self.Inum = Inum
        self.Hnum = Hnum
        self.Onum = Onum

        self.lr = 0.1

        self.weightsIH = np.random.rand(self.Hnum, self.Inum) * 2 - 1
        self.weightsHO = np.random.rand(self.Onum, self.Hnum) * 2 - 1

        self.biasH = np.random.rand(self.Hnum) * 2 - 1
        self.biasO = np.random.rand(self.Onum) * 2 - 1

    def feedForward(self, inputs):
        hidden = np.dot(self.weightsIH, np.array(inputs))
        hidden = hidden + self.biasH
        hidden = sigmoid(hidden)

        outputs = np.dot(self.weightsHO, hidden)
        outputs = outputs + self.biasO
        outputs = sigmoid(outputs)

        return outputs

    def train(self, inputs, targets):
        """
        NOTE : Always deal with column vectors as you do in maths.
        """
        # Feed Forward
        hidden = np.dot(self.weightsIH, np.array(inputs))
        hidden = hidden + self.biasH
        hidden = sigmoid(hidden)

        outputs = np.dot(self.weightsHO, hidden)
        outputs = outputs + self.biasO
        outputs = sigmoid(outputs)
        # Calculate errors
        errorsO = np.array(targets) - outputs
        errorsO = errorsO[:, np.newaxis] # errorsO is a column now

        # Calculate gradients with derivitive of sigmoid
        gradientsO_ = dsigmoid(outputs)
        # Convert gradientsO also to column vector before taking product
        gradientsO_ = gradientsO_[:, np.newaxis] * errorsO # Hadamard product to get a new column vector
        gradientsO = gradientsO_ * self.lr

        # Calculate deltas
        hiddenT = hidden[np.newaxis] # hidden is a column now
        weightsHODeltas = np.dot(gradientsO, hiddenT)

        # Adjust weights by deltas
        self.weightsHO = self.weightsHO + weightsHODeltas

        # Adjust bias by gradients
        self.biasO = self.biasO + gradientsO.reshape(self.biasO.shape)

        # Hidden layer
        errorsH = np.dot(np.transpose(self.weightsHO), errorsO) # You had a conceptual mistake here. You don't incoporate learning rate here

        # Calculate gradients with derivitive of sigmoid
        gradientsH = dsigmoid(hidden)
        gradientsH = gradientsH[:, np.newaxis] * errorsH
        gradientsH = gradientsH * self.lr

        # Calculate deltas
        inputsT = np.array(inputs)[np.newaxis]
        weightsIHDeltas = np.dot(gradientsH, inputsT)

        # Adjust weights by deltas
        self.weightsIH = self.weightsIH + weightsIHDeltas

        # Adjust bias by gradients
        self.biasH = self.biasH + gradientsH.reshape(self.biasH.shape)
```

Here is the code for XOR I'm running on it:

```
from NN import NeuralNetwork
from random import shuffle, choice

def main():
    nn = NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1)

    dataset = [
        {
            "inputs": [0, 0],
            "outputs": 0
        },
        {
            "inputs": [0, 1],
            "outputs": 1
        },
        {
            "inputs": [1, 0],
            "outputs": 1
        },
        {
            "inputs": [1, 1],
            "outputs": 0
        }
    ]


    for x in range(10000):
        for data in dataset:
            nn.train(data["inputs"], data["outputs"])
        shuffle(dataset)

    print(nn.feedForward([0, 0]))
    print(nn.feedForward([0, 1]))
    print(nn.feedForward([1, 0]))
    print(nn.feedForward([1, 1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here are the results:

```
[ 0.04557893]
[ 0.96304187]
[ 0.96304197]
[ 0.03685831]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are getting confused with the dimensions of a numpy array. While writing ML code in numpy, it is easier to deal with column vectors because that is what you do while deriving the equation on paper. Also, there was a logical mistake in your code. Below is the corrected code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from random import shuffle

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def dsigmoid(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, Inum, Hnum, Onum):
        self.Inum = Inum
        self.Hnum = Hnum
        self.Onum = Onum

        self.lr = 0.1

        self.weightsIH = np.random.rand(self.Hnum, self.Inum) * 2 - 1
        self.weightsHO = np.random.rand(self.Onum, self.Hnum) * 2 - 1

        self.biasH = np.random.rand(self.Hnum) * 2 - 1
        self.biasO = np.random.rand(self.Onum) * 2 - 1

    def feedForward(self, inputs):
        hidden = np.dot(self.weightsIH, np.array(inputs))
        hidden = hidden + self.biasH
        hidden = sigmoid(hidden)

        outputs = np.dot(self.weightsHO, hidden)
        outputs = outputs + self.biasO
        outputs = sigmoid(outputs)

        return outputs

    def train(self, inputs, targets):
        """
        NOTE : Always deal with column vectors as you do in maths.
        """
        # Feed Forward
        hidden = np.dot(self.weightsIH, np.array(inputs))
        hidden = hidden + self.biasH
        hidden = sigmoid(hidden)

        outputs = np.dot(self.weightsHO, hidden)
        outputs = outputs + self.biasO
        outputs = sigmoid(outputs)
        # Calculate errors
        errorsO = np.array(targets) - outputs
        errorsO = errorsO[:, np.newaxis] # errorsO is a column now

        # Calculate gradients with derivitive of sigmoid
        gradientsO_ = dsigmoid(outputs)
        # Convert gradientsO also to column vector before taking product
        gradientsO_ = gradientsO_[:, np.newaxis] * errorsO # Hadamard product to get a new column vector
        gradientsO = gradientsO_ * self.lr

        # Calculate deltas
        hiddenT = hidden[:, np.newaxis] # hidden is a column now
        weightsHODeltas = np.dot(hiddenT, gradientsO.T)

        # Adjust weights by deltas
        self.weightsHO = self.weightsHO + weightsHODeltas.reshape(self.weightsHO.shape)

        # Adjust bias by gradients
        self.biasO = self.biasO + gradientsO.reshape(self.biasO.shape)

        # Hidden layer
        errorsH = np.dot(np.transpose(self.weightsHO), gradientsO_) # You had a conceptual mistake here. You don't incoporate learning rate here

        # Calculate gradients with derivitive of sigmoid
        gradientsH = dsigmoid(hidden)
        gradientsH = gradientsH[:, np.newaxis] * errorsH
        gradientsH = gradientsH * self.lr

        # Calculate deltas
        inputsT = np.array(inputs)[:, np.newaxis]
        weightsIHDeltas = np.dot(inputsT, gradientsH.T)

        # Adjust weights by deltas
        self.weightsIH = self.weightsIH + weightsIHDeltas.reshape(self.weightsIH.shape)

        # Adjust bias by gradients
        self.biasH = self.biasH + gradientsH.reshape(self.biasH.shape)

def main():
    nn = NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1)

    dataset = [
        {
            "inputs": [0, 0],
            "outputs": 0
        },
        {
            "inputs": [0, 1],
            "outputs": 1
        },
        {
            "inputs": [1, 0],
            "outputs": 1
        },
        {
            "inputs": [1, 1],
            "outputs": 0
        }
    ]


    for x in range(100):
        for data in dataset:
            # print(data)
            nn.train(data["inputs"], data["outputs"])
        shuffle(dataset)

    for data in dataset:
        print(data)
        nn.feedForward(data["inputs"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

P.S : Also, you can improve your code quality by not repeating code as you do with the feedforward part.

Comment: Mine seems to work a lot worse than in the vid, running it exactly the same way as in [this vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlqinMNM4xs) gives me worse [results](https://pastebin.com/PArEYmU2)...

Comment: I've changed your code to better fit the source code of the tutorial and it works most of the time now! Thank you!